# log4net RollingFileAppender requiring call to Configure() on every log attempt

Tags: c#, log4net

Not sure whats going on here, but my logging code will not write to the rollingFileAppender unless I call XmlConfigurator.Configure() on every call.  I have turned on debugging in the following code and can confirm that when Configure is called just the one time in the constructor it does appear to be pulling in my configuration, but when Log() is actually called, nothing happens to the log file OR shows up in the debug window.
If I uncomment that call to Configure() in Log() and let it reconfigure on every call, then it works just fine, but I don't think that is intended usage.

Bonus Points! - I notice that the very first call to log.Info() is not logging, but all subsequent ones in each run of the process are fine.

Thanks!

```
  public static class LogToFile
{
    public const string RollingFileAppenderName = "RollingFileLogger";

    static LogToFile()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    public static void Log(string fileNameBase, string message, string context)
    {
        if (fileNameBase == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fileNameBase");
        if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        //log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.log", fileNameBase, context);
        string fullFileName = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.LogFilePath, fileName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(Properties.Settings.Default.LogFilePath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Properties.Settings.Default.LogFilePath);

        LogicalThreadContext.Properties["LogName"] = string.Format(fullFileName);
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(RollingFileAppenderName);

        log.Info(message);
    }
}

    <appender name="rollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
  <countDirection value="-1"/>
  <LockingModel value="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <immediateFlush value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="AlertMessageHandler Message : %-25date [%thread] - %newline%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuall sgmoore's advice led me to the solution.  If I can just name the log file on the Appender object instead of messsing with the config file Property, then calling ActivateOptions works just fine.  Here's the working code.  Thanks!

```
public static class LogToFile
{
    public const string RollingFileLoggerName = "RollingFileLogger";

    public const string RollingFileAppenderName = "rollingFileAppender";

    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(RollingFileLoggerName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs to log4net rollingFileAppender
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileNameBase">prefix of log filename</param>
    /// <param name="message">log4net message property</param>
    /// <param name="context">files grouped by context</param>
    public static void Log(string fileNameBase, string message, string context)
    {
        if (fileNameBase == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fileNameBase");
        if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.log", fileNameBase, context);
        string fullFileName = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.LogFilePath, fileName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(Properties.Settings.Default.LogFilePath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Properties.Settings.Default.LogFilePath);

        ActivateAppenderOptions(string.Format(fullFileName));

        Logger.Info(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the appender in log4net after setting the log file path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    private static void ActivateAppenderOptions(string filename)
    {
        var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        var appenders = hierarchy.GetAppenders();
        foreach (
            var rfa in appenders.OfType<RollingFileAppender>().Where(rfa => rfa.Name == RollingFileAppenderName))
        {
            rfa.File = filename;
            rfa.ActivateOptions();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration file says that the logfile name is set to use the LogName property which you are changing at runtime. I always thought you were not allowed to change the properties on  an appender at runtime without reinitialising the appender (by called ActivateOptions) or by calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() which is easier but will do a lot more.

Also in your log method, if you call XmlConfigurator.Configure() **before** setting LogName, then I would suspect your first call would fail (trying to write to null) and your second call  would write to the file that was supposed to be used with the first call.

If you move XmlConfigurator.Configure() to **after** you set LogName, it should work properly.

Comment: What you say makes a lot of sense.  :)  I tried getting my RollingFileAppender and calling ActivateOptions(), but that doesnt work.  Maybe something about setting that LogName Property is beyond the scope of what ActivateOptions() can refresh.  So I'm stuck calling configure...BUT you did lead me towards calling Configure() after changing the Property, which means I'm not missing the first message or writing to the wrong file anymore.  Thanks for that!

Comment: If you have a reference to the appender, then you should be able to directly set its File property to fullFileName and then call ActivateOptions which may mean you don't need the LogName property.

Comment: I see you beat to that conclusion -)

Comment: Yeah, I did.  But only because you got me thinking more about messing with the appender in code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the log variable outside out your method that way:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogToFile));
```

That's the way I use it and I have to problem. However, in my case, I don't log in a static class.

Also, I have my appender information is in a file that I specify in the XmlConfigurator.Configure() function.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(configFile));
```

Comment: I tried moving the ILog out, didnt change anything.  I did notice that I dont need to call Configure on EVERY logging call, but I do need to call it until the first successful message.  That could explain why calling it in the constructor isn't working (that log4net is not logging the first message).